# signalr OnDisconnected method

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

I am trying to implement an app in which I have used signalr to detect the time at which client is disconnected from server..my hub is like this..
I am using version 0.2.0-alpha

```
[HubName("TrappistHub")]
public class TrappistHub : Hub
{

    public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
    {
        return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
    }

    public void SendReport(TestAttendees testAttendee)
    {
        Clients.All.getReport(testAttendee);
    }

}
```

and DisconnectTime is set default. but when I disconnect from from server OnDisconnected method gets hit after 50 secs instead of 30..and when I set the DisconnectTime to 10 secs or 20 secs it is not getting hit at all..but when I refresh the page it is getting hit...I dont understand why..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version you are using (i.e. 0.2.0-alpha) is not supported. Use the new version that shipped last week - 1.0.0-alpha1. See the [announcement](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/09/14/announcing-signalr-for-asp-net-core-2-0/) for more details.

Comment: I am using Asp.net core 1.1

Comment: This is not a supported version so I don't think anyone will want to spend time on debugging this. Can you move to ASP.NET Core 2.0?

Comment: I have a big application running on .net core 1.1 and most of my packages are according to that..won't there be any effect..If I switch to 2.0..?

Comment: And After I switch to .net core 2.0 , what exactly I need to do with signalr.. so that If my application crashes or shutdown OnDisconnected method gets called immediately or a specified time set by me..It would be very helpful If u explain or give some link to refer..

Comment: These settings are not there anymore :D. This is a rewrite so this code does not exist so you will very likely not hit this particular issue. Read [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/09/14/announcing-signalr-for-asp-net-core-2-0/) to get started.